# webjobs json data to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to read azure webjobs services json data for logs using REST API, I am able to get the data in dataframe with columns, but I need lastrun column (one of the column) data to be available in tabular format, where data available in  key:value format as shown below picture

Example:

```
latest_run
0,"{'id': '202011160826295419', 'name': '202011160826295419','job_name': 'failjob','}"
1,"{'id': '202011160826295419', 'name': '202011160826295419','job_name': 'passjob','}"
```

now I want to display all id, job_name in a data frame format, any help please thanks in advance

Below is my code

```
data = response.json()
# print(data)
df = pd.read_json(json.dumps(data), orient='records')
# df = json.loads(json.dumps(data))

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df = df["latest_run"]
df.to_csv('file1.csv')
print(df)
```

Data:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First things first, your JSON is not formatted properly (it isn't correct JSON). There is an extra opening quote at the end, and JSON should have double quotes all over. Pretending it's correct JSON for now, this is how you could load it:

```py
# NOTE: You can also open a CSV file directly
import io
csv_content = """latest_run
0,"{'id': '202011160826295419', 'name': '202011160826295419','job_name': 'failjob'}"
1,"{'id': '202011160826295419', 'name': '202011160826295419','job_name': 'passjob'}"
"""
csv_file = io.StringIO(csv_content)


import csv
import json
import pandas

# Create a CSV reader (this can also be a file using 'open("myfile.csv", "r")' )
reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=",")

# Skip the first line (header)
next(reader)

# Load the rest of the data
data = [row for row in reader]

# Create a dataframe, loading the JSON as it goes in
df = pandas.DataFrame([json.loads(row[1].replace("'", "\"")) for row in data], index=[int(row[0]) for row in data])
```

Comment: @shaik, no problem! Please accept the answer if it is what you're looking for. That helps others in finding the answers they need as well.